# Code won't work properly in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, jsfiddle

Here is what is supposed to happen:

The moment the user chooses an option a certain combination of input fields should show up along with two tables.

When the user fills in the input fields and clicks the button, the results should appear in the tables.

Those tables aren't showing up. The input fields don't even show up in js fiddle.

It only works in the newest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE.

Not in firefox 6.0 or IE 9.08.

I made the mistake of coding exclusively in Chrome at home to discover that my code doesn't work when I tried to continue working at school.

I used jsfiddle.net to validate my code and did so successfully. Although it still won't work. It doesn't even show up properly inside jsFiddle.

Here is the fiddle to demo the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2nz5/5/

Comment: I edited my question to include that. sorry.

Comment: Do you get errors in the JS console?

Comment: in jsfiddle there aren't any errors. I fixed any errors it gave so that it says "your code is valid".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputTable method contains line Caption.align = "middle", which cannot be executed in IE and apparently in FF as well. replace it with Caption.style.textAlign = "middle"; and it will fix the problem.

The same with MCaption.

But the best you can do here is to define all styles like that in css.

Comment: I commented out all those styles and it appears to work in IE, Safari, and Chrome but not firefox.

The same problem occurs.

Comment: if you will take a look at the error console in FF (Ctrl+Shift+J =) you will see the following error:  child is not defined.  That is because firefox can't find your div with id="child". You should use var child = document.getElementById("child"); before calling child.appendChild...

Comment: when I add var child = document.getElementById("child"); it stops working in all my browsers. The latest of firefox, IE, Safari and chrome.

Comment: are you aware of debugging? e.g. to debug jsvascript in IE 9, you have to press f12 and then go to script tab - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478, to debug in firefox use FireBug, in other browser their corresponding developer tools can be invoked also via f12. try to debug your outputTable function and see what's wrong exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In your js fiddle you were getting this error: `inputOutputCreator is not defined`. It is because you are loading your js in the mootools `onLoad` function. Change it from `onLoad` to `no wrap` in the jsfiddle settings to the left. With that changed it worked just fine for me.

Comment: Nice! That's cool. I don't get how those options work or what they do. Although I'm still having the same problem in firefox.